# Does convergence of moment generating functions imply convergence of moments?

Tags: probability-theory

Well, the heading says it. If $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence of random variables and $X$ is a random variable such that $\mathbb{E}e^{t X_n} \rightarrow \mathbb{E} e^{tX}$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$, then does it imply that $\mathbb{E} X_n^k \rightarrow \mathbb{E} X^k$ for all $k \geq 1$? If so, what theorem in analysis makes this true?

Answer (score 0):

Just the Lévy's continuity theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A9vy%27s_continuity_theorem
$$X_n\to X $$
in distribution. Apply the bounded convergence theorem
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem
then $$\mathbb{E}X_n\to \mathbb{E} X $$